# BJT transistor working and construction

Tags: transistors, bjt, semiconductors

Why is electron concentration zero at collector side of the base in BJT transistor? And if electron concentration decreases with distance and becomes zero at the end base region how can it produce considerable amount of collector current?

Comment: with charges injected from the base pin into the base region, the emitter emits opposite-polarity charges with purpose of annihilating the base charges. Most miss, and are collected in the collector region. Now about that zero-electron concentration......is this for NPN or PNP?

Answer (score 0):

First, in normal operation, the base-collector junction is reverse-biased.  This causes free carriers (electrons or holes, depending on NPN or PNP respectively) to migrate across the junction, and creates a depletion region around the junction.

Second, when current carriers are injected from the emitter into the base (by adjusting the base-emitter voltage), those carriers, and the resulting current, have to go somewhere.  Some of them, usually around 1-2%, will recombine in the base, giving rise to base current.  Most of them will feel the attractive force from the reverse-biased base-collector junction, and flow to the collector, giving rise to collector current.

The recombination in base vs. continue to collector ratio is of course the ratio of collector current to base current, and is a design parameter of the transistor.

The above is SIMPLIFIED, with lots of handwaving.